# Angular 13 HttpClient catchError handling

Tags: angular

I would like to catch a specific 404 http error from a backend to deal with error in a component.

The service is :

```ts
      findOne(id: number): Observable<Intern | undefined> {
        return this.httpClient.get<any>(
          `${environment.apiRoot}intern/${id}`, // http://127.0.0.1/intern/999,
          {
            observe: 'response'
          }
        )
        .pipe(
          take(1),
          catchError((error) => {
            Logger.error('F****g error was raised');
            return throwError(() => new Error('Blah'));
          }),
          map((response: HttpResponse<any>) => {
              Logger.error(`Error : ${response.status}`);
              // Récupérer le "ça" et en faire un vrai Intern
              const rawIntern: any = response.body;
    
              const intern: Intern = new Intern();
              intern.id = rawIntern.id;
              intern.name = rawIntern.name;
              intern.firstname = rawIntern.firstName;
              intern.birthDate = new Date(rawIntern.birthDate);
              intern.address = rawIntern.address;
              intern.phoneNumber = rawIntern.phoneNumber;
              intern.email = rawIntern.email;
    
              return intern;
          })
        )
      }
```

In the component, subscribe to Observable this way :

```ts
    this.internService.findOne(this._id).subscribe({
              next: (intern: Intern | undefined) => {
                this.intern = intern;
              },
              error: (error) => {
                Logger.error(JSON.stringify(error));
              }
            }
            );
```

Finally:

error attribute in subscribe give an empty object ! not as expected 'Blah'.

But i got the Object i need (here an Intern model) if backend send a 200...

What's my bad ?

Regards

Comment: do you have a stackblitz possibly?

Comment: Does the same happen if you don't `observe: 'response'`?

Comment: If you `console.log` the errors inside of the `catchError` or inside the subscribe `error` handler, does it log

Comment: Well, will try without observe: response, and make a minimal reproductible repo... logs are both output in the catchError and error subscribe parameter, but in error of subscribe, error is empy

Comment: With or without obersve: 'response' behavior is the same... subscribe error function give an empty object